# can not use Nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, 14.04

Im using ubuntu 14.04. I installed bumblebee on my laptop uses nvidia geforce. I uninstalled bumblebee and installed nvidias official drivers but computer is still trying to use bumblebee with intel Ivybridge Mobile. It is written on "about this computer" section too. How can i switch graphic card to nvidia?

Answer (score 0):

whenever you need to use nvidia card open terminal and use

```
optirun %command%
```

where %command% is the program you want to run with nvidia GPU. 
For example

```
optirun google-chrome-stable
```

To confirm if drivers are working, run

```
glxspheres64
```

followed by

```
optirun glxspheres64
```

and see the difference in fps.

P.S if you are using 32-bit system, use "glxspheres" instead of "glxspheres64"

Comment: glxspheres64: command not found ---
[ 1699.186053] [ERROR]Error running "glxspheres64": No such file or directory --- what should i do now ?

Comment: glxspheres64 is a program found in bumblebee and since you are using a machine with a intel+nvidia hybrid, Id suggest installing bumblebee instructions can be found here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation 
Follow instructions for 13.10 and after basic bumblebee install, run

    sudo apt-get install virtualgl virtualgl-libs-ia32